# Ionic, Socket.io and AngularJS, Acknowleage doesnt work

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sockets

I'm using Ionic and Socket.io, and I have a problem to "fire" the acknowleage callback of emits..

In normal javascript the client side is:

```
function ack(response){
console.log(response);
}
socket.emit('message',{data:"data"}, ack);
```

When the server recibe the message the client fire that function, the server side is..

```
socket.on('message',function(data,fn){
fn({data:"response"});
});
```

So, when the server execute the fn({data:"response"}), the client fire the ack function.

I build with ionic framework this factory:

```
services.factory('$socket', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {

  var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:9564');

  function on(eventName, callback){

    console.log(eventName);

    socket.on(eventName, function () {  
      var args = arguments;
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
      });
    });
  }

  function emit(eventName, data, callback){
    socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {  
      var args = arguments;
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        callback.apply(socket, args);
      });
    });
  }

  return {
    on: on,
    emit: emit
  };
}]);
```

And in my UserCtrl I try to use in this way:

```
function OnLogin(data){
      console.log(data);
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }

    $scope.doLogin = function() {
      $socket.emit('user:login', $scope.loginData, OnLogin);
    };
```

The problem is that the function OnLogin is never called, I try puting that function into the $scope.OnLogin, but is the same.

Eny solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure the url local host is the same for the script added? (I.e with the other js scripts included, above the internal js files?)

Comment: Yes, the problem was the Internet permition in AndroidManifiest. :P. Thanks.